# Exim send e-mails to another mx server

Tags: exim

I have two servers one for web and other for e-mail.

The web server has installed exim for send notifications to clients but I can't receive emails from the same domain in the e-mail server because all the emails sent from web server stay right there.

The web server and email server have their respective dns entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the vdomain driver to use dnslookup and transport to remote_smtp in the exim conf.
All email sent to the same domain now just look for mx register in the dns.

```
vdomain:
  debug_print = "R: vdomain for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim.domains
  local_parts = lsearch;/etc/exim.domains/$domain
  transport = remote_smtp
```